# Microsoft Access: Present button to create record if none exists

Tags: forms, ms-access

I have a Microsoft Access 2007 form, which has the following Form Source:

```
SELECT referrals.referral_date, referrals.*, schools.*, EAL_SLA_Assessment.*, referrals.forename & " " & referrals.surname AS combinedName, religions.religion, ethnicities.ethnicity
FROM (((referrals LEFT JOIN schools ON referrals.LCC_no = schools.LCC_no) LEFT JOIN ethnicities ON referrals.ethnicity = ethnicities.ID) LEFT JOIN religions ON referrals.religion = religions.ID) LEFT JOIN EAL_SLA_Assessment ON referrals.referral_number = EAL_SLA_Assessment.sla_id
ORDER BY referrals.referral_date DESC;
```

The form looks like this:

[image: Database Front End]

The 'SLA details' section of the form, is populated by the `'LEFT JOIN EAL_SLA_Assessment ON referrals.referral_number = EAL_SLA_Assessment.sla_id'` section of the query, and this query may return a record (if one exists) or may return NULL (if no record exists).

What I want is for the user to be presented with a button titled "Create SLA" (Service Level Agreement) if none exists, and the records retrieved by the query (if it finds one)

I know how I'd do this in PHP using an `IF(NULL($query['SLA_id'])) {} ELSE {}` statement, but my knowledge of Access is less thorough and I'm struggling to work out how to do it...

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Access VBA you can check for `IsNull(Me.Fieldname)`. The best event to handle this is probably `On Current`, since it's a per record thing.

Something like:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Current()
    Me.cmdCreateSLA.Visible = IsNull(Me.EAL_SLA_Assessment.sla_id)
End Sub
```

Note: if it's possible that `cmdCreateSLA` has the focus when `Form_Current()` is run, use `Me.someOtherControl.SetFocus` before trying to make the button invisible.

Problem: the tab "SLA Details" seems to contain a subform, since it's completely empty in your screenshot. So you can't put the button in there - the subform with the button is only shown when there is a record.

So the button must be outside the subform.